# Connecting two pictures from two specified points

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, corel-draw, autocad

The size of my scanner is A4, but the sheet I want to scan is bigger.

I marked it and scanned it twice.

Is there a software to connect the two pictures exactly at the two marked points?

Is it possible to do that with one of the softwares **Corel**, **Photoshop**, **AutoCAD** ...?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Will be easiest to do in Photoshop.

Open one file.
Increase Art-board size to fit both images.
Drag in other file.
Set that new layer to multiply, or set transparency to 50%.
Then move around till it matches.
Set blending mode to normal again.

Also there is the option of using File / Automate / Photomerge. This will combine (/ position) two images into one. But it may stretch some bits, which in your case you probably don't want.

Answer (score 1):

A little to add to the older answer:

Use blending mode Difference when you compare how the layers fit. Your both scans have quite the same exposure and light colors, so the overlapping area is easy to see nearly black when the points match. You must as well move and rotate the upper layer:

[image]

Rotating and moving is as easy if you have made the Transform Control handles visible in the info bar. Beware: It's as easy to stretch a layer unintentionally. Press Escape if that happens. The edits are fixed when you press Enter.

It's useful to match at first one of your control points only by moving the upper layer. Then move the rotation center to the matched point. Match the other control point by rotating.

There's no need to stretch the upper layer if you and your scanner scan consistently. It's possible that the original is a little curved and the curvature is straightened differently in the scans. To fix it, too some stretching is needed, but it's impossible to say which of the scans is less distorted. For that purpose some surely stable reference should be included.

As you will see 1 px residual errors are possible due the quantized nature of the scanned images.

The upper layer has some white which covers the lower layer. Make a selection and delete a slice. I guess you have added it afterwards when preparing the images for the question. The result is shown in the next image:

[image]

There's a minor exposure difference which can be seen as a border. It may be harmful or not depending on your final application. To fix it apply Image > Adjustment > Curves to one of the layers. Here the upper one is a little darker. It's made brighter:

[image]

Merge the layers after you are sure they fit. You may want to remove the white background. That subject is skipped here, because it's well presented in Photoshop tutorials.